# NodeJS: disable SO_REUSEADDR or otherwise guarantee ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, sockets, testing

I'm trying to write a test in Node for the behavior of a networking client when it fails to make a TCP connection to a given server. Ideally, I'd like this to be as close as possible to the ECONNREFUSED case rather than some other error like DNS lookup failure, connection closed before receiving a response, etc.

A method I've tried is to make a server that listens binding port 0, then close the server, then connect to the port that was chosen when the server listened. This mostly works, but in CI when many tests are running in parallel sometimes some other test claims the port that was just bound and closed.

If this were C, I could just not set `SO_REUSEADDR` when binding the port, which should prevent the port from being quickly reused. But as far as I can tell, there's no way in Node to create a listening socket without `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Any thoughts about achieving this goal? Things I've thought about but not quite gotten to work include:

- finding an npm package that lets me `setsockopt` to turn off `SO_REUSEADDR` (though I suspect that once the `bind` has happened it's too late?)
- finding some other mechanism that isn't `net.Server` to bind to a port without `SO_REUSEADDR`
- finding a different mechanism of tricking the client into thinking the connection was refused

(That said, some of the tests I'm writing involve "first the connection works and a later connection doesn't" so ideally something that lets me actually have a real server would be great --- ie my first idea somehow!)

Comment: "_All net.Socket are set to SO_REUSEADDR_" according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/net.html#serverlisten).

Comment: @rveerd yes, I agree, it's pretty clearly [unconditional](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e17e903188b30a1acd3a65594dc5a1847b24ac73/deps/uv/src/unix/tcp.c#L164-L165) in the source, and I couldn't find any place in the source that lets you call arbitrary `setsockopt` on sockets from JS (plus I assume you have to do it before you bind anyway).